# Write function not using the seekp value

Tags: c++, filestream, seek

I'm trying to use C++ to write an entry in a specific place in a file

so basicly I have

```
ofstream ofs("file.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
ofs.seekp(220, ios::beg);
ofs.write((char *)&i, sizeof(i));
```

But no matter what I do it always write at the end of the file.

I suppose this is related to `iso::app` because according to the documentation

```
app (append) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation
```

But if I use **ate** or nothing it always erases the content of the file.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the `ios::app` that's causing this behaviour. Replace it with `ios::in | ios::out`.

**edit:** It wasn't clear from your question, but your comments suggest that you're trying to *insert* data in the middle of the file, rather than *overwrite* a portion of the file. If that is indeed the case, you pretty much have to use a second file for that.

Comment: ofstream default is to ios::out. Adding ios::in breaks the program.

Comment: @Paté: Well, the default is irrelevant since you're not using it (you're using `ios::binary...`). Also, when you say "breaks", in what way exactly?

Comment: @Paté: Yes, you can't seek then insert data. It will just start overwriting existing data. You would have to output the first part (up until where you want to insert), insert the new data, then append the rest.

Answer (score 5):

## File append mode

If the OS (and network file system, if applicable) supports append mode, setting append mode guarantees that **data written does not overwrite existing data** in the file when there are multiple writers. That's something you cannot do without append mode, because of the race between seek and write from different processes. It is an important guarantee for log files.

In append mode, you can only write at end of file by definition.

## Iostream open modes

According to [ofstream.cons], `ofstream (s, mode)` calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode|ios_base::out)`.

According to the table "File open modes" in [filebuf.members], the behaviour of `filebuf::open` is defined in term of `fopen` open modes:

- `out` means "w"
- `app` and `app|out` mean "a"
- `in|out` means "r+"
- `in|out|trunc` means "w+"

According to `fopen man`, the modes mean:

- **r+**    Open for reading and writing.
- **w**    Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
- **w+**    Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.
- **a**    Open for appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist.

Finally, `ate` means `fseek(file,0,SEEK_END)`.

So, if you want to open for writing at arbitrary position, without destroying the existing data, you need `fopen(s,"r+")` or `ofstream (s, ios::in|ios::out)`.

IOW, in C/C++ you also need read access to a file to open it for writing without overwriting it!

## POSIX world

You may want to use the POSIX `open` function instead, in order to directly access the POSIX open flags: `O_READ`, `O_WRITE`, `O_CREAT`, `O_EXCL`, `O_TRUNC`... They are not only much more powerful, but also independent orthogonal flags and well-behaved, unlike `filebuf::open` flags.

Of course, this function is not part of standard C++. I believe all systems relevant for normal programming (not niche markets with special characteristics) support `open`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ios::out` instead of `ios::app`?

**EDIT:**

After reading the docs that @curiousguy referenced it looks like you would need `ios::in | ios::out` instead of just `ios::out` to keep from truncating.

Comment: You want to truncate the existing file?