# reposition in a file and replace a string with another in c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the function tellp from C++. Having the code below, instead of replacing "AAAAAA" with "CCCCCC", the resulting file prints: "AAAAAA\n" "CCCCCC\n".

```
ofstream file;
file.open("log.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
file.write ....

long posLog1 = file.tellp(); -> prints 122
file << "AAAAAA" << endl;
long posLog2 = file.tellp(); -> prints 129
file.seekp (posLog2 - 7);   
long posLog2 = file.tellp(); -> prints 122
file << "CCCCCC" << endl;
long posLog3 = file.tellp(); -> prints 136 instead of 129
```

Comment: You should omit the `std::endl` then if you don't want to have the `'\n'`!

Comment: I don't see you replacing any string.

Comment: I want to replace the string in file when i do file.seekp (posLog2 - 7); I replaced std::endl with "\n" but doesn't work. I need to have "\n" at the end of the line.

Comment: _I replaced std::endl with "\n"_ Then omit `std::endl` for your 2nd output `file << "CCCCCC";`

Comment: I used VS2010 and your code and it works just fine.

Comment: The results of seeking to `posLog2 - 7` are undefined behavior.

Comment: I launched your code and compiled with gcc and it works fine (I only changed the second "long posLog2" in something else to avoid the dual definition. @JamesKanze why do you say the file.seekp(posLog2-7) is undefined? I see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/ and it seems to be the correct way to operate.

Comment: I edited the code. I actually open the file with the option ::app. And I noticed that if open like this "file.open("log.txt", ios::out|ios::app);" doesn't work but with ::trunc works. Anyone has any idea why it doesn't work with ::app?. Thanks.

Comment: Now it makes sense, ::app opens in appending mode only. Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928648/write-function-not-using-the-seekp-value

Comment: @Jekyll Because the standard says so.  There are a significant
number of constraints concerning seeking in a `filebuf`.  In
particular: "If sp [the position argument] has not been obtained
by a previous successful call to one of the positioning
functions (`seekoff` or `seekpos` [called by `seek[pg]` and
`tell[pg]`) on the same file the effects are undefined."  You
can't do any arithmetic and expect it to work.  (In practice, it will work under Unix, and some of the time under Windows.)