# fstream: cannot write in the middle of a file

Tags: c++, insert, fstream

I cannot write text in the middle of a file. 
I can correctly find the point where to add the text, and I can check it with `tellg()/tellp()`. But when, after a `seekp()`, I add the new text:

```
myfstream << "new text" << endl;
```

This is appended to the end of the file.

What is wrong in what I am doing?

Comment: You can't insert in the middle of a file, you can only overwrite. It's odd that the text is appended, but it's impossible to say why that happens unless you post the code.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I do not want to insert, just overwrite from a certain point onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928648/write-function-not-using-the-seekp-value), since I opened the file in append mode, then every write operation will append, even after a seekp().

The solution is to open the file in ios::in | ios::out mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there's no way to write in the middle of a file with fstream.
You must copy the hole file into you programm and edit your text and write it back into the file.

Otherwise you could overwrite the line with std::ostream::seekp()